# Removing item from download list

Tags: notifications, downloading

HTC One S, Android 4.1.1, HTC Sense 4+

I was messing around with a media server at home and started a download of a large file. This file is now gone from the source but the phone is still trying to download it, i.e. it's in the notification list that I drag down from the top of the screen. How do I remove an item from that list?

Comment: Do you have a "Downloads" app in your app drawer?

Comment: Have tried to kill the app you're using to download? Or just restart your device.

Comment: It's just the default manager for downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Killing the Download app (i.e. Force Stop) and then rebooting cleared it.